# Compiler error while programming ic

Tags: c, eclipse

MY friend is trying to program a shift register ic 74hc595 with 8051 microcontroller attached to display a moving led message.
But my compiler is giving me error in `send_data(alf(a));`

Here is code->

```
#include<8051.h>
#define clock P2_0
#define data_bit P2_1
#define latch P2_2
#define shift 8
void delay(unsigned int i)
{
    int k=0;
    while(k<i)
    {
        k++;
    }
}
void send_data(unsigned char temp)
   {
   unsigned char i;
   unsigned char dd;
   latch=0;
   clock=0;
   for(i=0;i<shift;i++){
   dd=temp>>i;
   if(dd&1)
                        data_bit=1;
             else
                        data_bit=0;
   clock=1;
   clock=0;
                       }
   latch=1;
   }
unsigned char alf[]={16,6,6,16};
void main()
{
unsigned char a;
  while(1){
   for(a=0;a<4;a++)
   {
   send_data(alf(a));
   delay(10000);
   }
  }
}
```

Since its my friend who is making, i dont have much info about it. But if anything else is needed, please tell and i will provide but please help me solve this prob.
Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the programming language, and at least post the error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
send_data(alf(a));
```

should be

```
send_data(alf[a]);
```

On the other hand, the body of `delay` can be optimized (and removed) by your compiler, take a look to the [volatile keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable)

Answer (score 0):

In your case `alf` is an array not a function. If `alf` is a function then you can call `alf(a)`. For array you need to pass index so you need to call `alf[a].`